# EDI FILE Convert into XML Using Biztalk

Tags: c#, xml, biztalk, edi, biztalk-mapper

I have multiple EDI files and I try to convert those EDI files into XML using BizTalk.

Here is my EDI file:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *16*SENDER1        *1B*RECEIVER1      *071216*1406*U*00204*000000263*1*T*>~
GS*IN*SENDER1*RECEIVER1*20071216*1406*000000001*X*004010~
ST*850*0001~
BEG*00*SA*XX-1234**20170301**NA~
PER*BD*ED SMITH*TE*8001234567~
TAX*53247765*SP*CA*********9~
N1*BY*ABC AEROSPACE*9*1234567890101~
N2*AIRCRAFT DIVISION~
N3*2000 JET BLVD~
N4*FIGHTER TOWN*CA*98898~
PO1*1*25*EA*36*PE*MG*XYZ-1234~
MEA*WT*WT*10*OZ~
IT8*******B0~
SCH*25*EA***106*20170615~
CTT*1~
AMT*TT*900~
SE*15*0001~
GE*1*000000001~
IEA*1*000000263~
```

Here is my mapping:

[image]

This is my Biztalk Services configuration:

[image]

Send port:

[image]

And here is the error I get while processing:

[image]

Comment: Should BIG be BEG?

Comment: No i don't think it is right beacuse in all the file it is BEG

Comment: Why is your mapping showing BIG?

Comment: I have used MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates In that it is BIG in all XSD file can you please help me to generated Receive schema.?

Comment: Do not have enough details.  The XSD file is text and can be edited with any text editor.  The are online checker  that you can use to verify the XSD file.

Comment: You're using an 811 source schema when the input file is 850.  That's why the segments aren't matching (BEG vs BIG)

Comment: Also in your source file the error is complaining about an invalid receiver qualifier, which appears as 1B in your source 850 file.  I've never seen 1B in that element before, but it could be correct.

Comment: @Andrew - can you please provide any 811 source schema file i need to give support of 811 File but i don't have that file and user is not provide the file as well so please provide me EDI 811 File.

Comment: @Andrew - I have 850 source schema but still facing same error.

Comment: See my second comment about hte receiver ID qualifier.  I'm assuming it has to match what's in the trading partner setup.  But BizTalk doesn't like the 1B in the ISA segment.